# JQuery: adding click function to existing toggle

Tags: jquery

How can I close this drawer when the canvas is clicked? Furthermore, because the drawer itself is in the canvas will clicking the drawer when it's open close it too? That would not be desirable. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle-nav').click(function(){
        toggleNav();
        });
    });
function toggleNav(){
    if ($('#site-wrapper').hasClass('show-nav')){
        // nav-close functions
        $('#site-wrapper').removeClass('show-nav');
    } else{
        // nav-open functions
        $('#site-wrapper').addClass('show-nav');
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8s42f/

Comment: What do you mean by "drawer" ?

Comment: "close this drawer when the canvas is clicked" -- smacks of Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/8s42f/3/

Updated JS:

```
$(function () {
    var $wrapper = $('#site-wrapper');
    function toggleNav (event) {
        $wrapper.toggleClass('show-nav');
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    function hideNav (event) {
        if (!$(event.target).is('#site-menu, #site-menu *'))
            $wrapper.removeClass('show-nav');
    }
    $('.toggle-nav').click(toggleNav);
    $('#site-wrapper').click(hideNav);
});
```

I made the following changes:

- Replaced duplicate lookups for `#site-wrapper` with a cached variable `$wrapper`
- Replaced `toggleNav()` logic with jQuery's `$.fn.toggleClass()` method
- Used `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent `.toggle-nav` clicks from triggering the `$wrapper` event
- Added `hideNav()` method and bound it to `$wrapper`
- Added check inside `hideNav()` to prevent clicks inside the nav from being caught.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really? This lets you click the 'canvas' and close the 'drawer'?

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:
 - canvas = document
 - drawer = #site-wrapper

Set your click handler on `document`. If anything other than `#site-wrapper` or its children are clicked, the "drawer" will be closed.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.id === 'site-wrapper' || $(e.target).closest('#site-wrapper').length) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (! $('#site-wrapper').hasClass('show-nav')) {
                toggleNav();
            }
        } else if ($('#site-wrapper').hasClass('show-nav')) {
            toggleNav();
        }
    });
});

function toggleNav() {
    $('#site-wrapper').toggleClass('show-nav');
}
```

And the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rodgolpe/8s42f/5/